# Prolog going though a list and turning the odd number to even by doubling all the odd numbers in the list

Tags: prolog

`toEven(L1, L2)` takes an input list of
integers and generates an output list `L2` which is `L1` with all odd integers changed into
even by doubling each odd number.

how do i do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempts and have a more specific question?

Answer (score 2):

```
toEven(L1, L1) :-
   maplist( \I^D^( I mod 2 =:= 1 -> D is 2*I ; D = I ), L1, L2)
```

using `library(lambda)` for
[SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/lambda.pl)|[SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/file_details/lambda/prolog/lambda.pl).

Or, without lambdas:

```
i_2i(I, D) :-
   ( I mod 2 =:= 1 -> D is 2*I ; D = I ).

toEven(L1, L2) :-
   maplist(i_2i, L1, L2).
```

Or, without maplist:

```
toEven([], []).
toEven([I|Is], [D|Ds]) :-
   ( I mod 2 =:= 1 -> D is 2*I ; D = I ),
   toEven(Is, Ds).
```

Comment: i dont understand that.  it would be helpfull to explain it and not just give the answer thanks. also would be helpfull to use     toEven(L1,L2)... in the answer

Comment: @g.s I would recommend consulting a Prolog manual and probably some tutorials. There are some online if you search for them.

Answer (score 2):

Using integers 'bit level' arithmetic and library(yall):

```erlang
?- [user].
|: toEven(L1, L2) :- maplist([N,M]>>(M is N<<(N mod 2)),L1,L2).
|: 
% user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- toEven([1,2,3,4,5],L2).
L2 = [2, 2, 6, 4, 10].
```

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is the stopping condition, when you reach the empty list after iterating through the list.

In the second statement, 1 is mod(H,2)  checks if the current value you are looking at is odd, then you assign H1 the double and append it by [H1|R]. (Lists in prolog are iterated through using the head and tail [H|T], head is the first element, the tail is the rest, so at the end we call the funciton toEven again with only the tail.)

The third statement, is for even values, you just call the function again, with its tail. (and of course, append the even value to the result list)

```
toEven([], []).
toEven([H|T], [H1|R]):- 1 is mod(H, 2), !, H1 is H*2, toEven(T, R).
toEven([H|T], [H|R]):- toEven(T, R).

toEven([1,2,3], R).
R=[2,2,6]
```

Comment: It doesn't, it gives the result "false", and I don't understand why you would query like that...

Comment: when i run this i get the error: "Undefined procedure: toEven/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)"

Comment: Only the first 3 lines are the code, the fourth is the query to call and the fifth is the result

Comment: can you help me with this I need to print stars n amount of times and on each next line there must be n-1 amount of stars this is what i have done so far:       star(N).
star(N) :- N-1, write("*").